# Jetpack: Display Site Title when no Site Logo

Tags: php, conditional-content, plugin-jetpack

How do I use an if else statement to display site title if no site logo is selected in the customizer when using jetpack? I have php code written but it's not working. I think it's because `function_exists('jetpack_the_site_logo')` checks to see if jet pack is activated, not whether the Site Logo section contains an image:

`<?php if (function_exists('jetpack_the_site_logo')) : ?>
            <?php jetpack_the_site_logo(); ?>
        <?php else : ?> 
            <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
        <?php endif; ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/Automattic/jetpack/blob/master/modules/theme-tools/site-logo/inc/functions.php#L75) the `jetpack_has_site_logo();` is what I need to accomplish this.